# Host Windows Media ActiveX Control pure C

Tags: c, winapi, activex, mingw, windows-media-player

Good day, I know, it's too hard to do, but i need know how to embed activex control (especially WMPlayer) in native window, using only win32 api (and no MS things such ATL, etc). I know how to deal with winapi, but don't know how to deal with com/activex.
Need the simpliest way to embed activex.

Comment: I`m going to se that...  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18417/Use-an-ActiveX-control-in-your-Win32-Project-witho

Comment: There's a nice cycle of articles by Jeff Glatt which you may find useful: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13601/COM-in-plain-C Also, you're contradicting yourself saying you're looking for the simplest way but refusing to use ATL. You'll eventually find yourself implementing at least `AtlAxAttachControl`.